# Rails update action fails to check params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, put

I am building a Rails API and found out that put request passes without required parameters. That is weird for me as app won't allow post request without parameters. Moreover, when I’m trying to update the spending without attributes via Rails console, it fails. But via Postman/CURL request passes successfully

The controller looks like this:

```
class SpendingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_spending, only: %i[show update destroy]

  def create
    spending = Spending.new(spending_params)
    spending.user = current_user
    spending.category = Category.find_by(id: spending_params[:category_id])

    if spending.valid?
      spending.save
      render json: SpendingSerializer.new(spending), status: :ok
    else
      render json: ActiveRecordErrorsSerializer.new(spending), status: :bad_request
    end
  end

  def index
    spendings = Spending.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("#{sort_spendings}")
    total_value = Spending.where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:amount).sum

    render json: {spendings: SpendingSerializer.new(spendings), total_amount: total_value}, status: :ok
  end

  def show
    if @spending.valid?
      render json: SpendingSerializer.new(@spending), status: :ok
    else
      render json: ActiveRecordErrorsSerializer.new(@spending), status: :not_found

    end
  end

  def update
    if @spending.valid?
      @spending.update(spending_params)
      render json: SpendingSerializer.new(@spending), status: :ok
    else
      render json: ActiveRecordErrorsSerializer.new(@spending), status: :bad_request
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @spending.destroy
      head :no_content
    else
      render json: ActiveRecordErrorsSerializer.new(@spending), status: :not_found
    end
  end

  private

  def spending_params
    params.require(:spending).permit(:description, :amount, :category_id)
  end

  def find_spending
    begin
      @spending = Spending.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      render json: {errors: "Spending with id #{params[:id]} not found"}, status: :not_found
    end
  end

  def sort_spendings
    sort = { sort_by: "created_at", sort_dir: "desc"}
    sort[:sort_by] = params[:sort_by].split(" ").first if params[:sort_by].present?
    sort[:sort_dir] = params[:sort_by].split(" ").last if params[:sort_by].present?
    sort.values.join(" ")
  end
end
```

And my model:

```
class Spending < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  validates :description,
            presence: true
end
```

I’m really out of ideas, why is that happening. Any guesses what can that be related to?

Comment: PUT request to not need to have all required parameters because it only updates already existing records and these records have already all required attributes set.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I’ve just realized that I was trying to catch not an error but standard behaviour, guess, I'm too stressed with a test task for a first coding job. And I do mean it when saying thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that I noticed is your `update` method. You check validation before updating the model. `@spending.valid?` always returns true in this case. My suggestion to modify it. `@spending.update(spending_params)` returns true if it update is successful and false if it fails.

```
def update
  if @spending.update(spending_params)
    render json: SpendingSerializer.new(@spending), status: :ok
  else
    render json: ActiveRecordErrorsSerializer.new(@spending), status: :bad_request
  end
end
```

`created` method an be also optimised. You don't need find and assign `category` separately. It will be assigned as all `spending_params`.

```
def create
  spending = Spending.new(spending_params)
  spending.user = current_user

  spending.save
    render json: SpendingSerializer.new(spending), status: :ok
  else
    render json: ActiveRecordErrorsSerializer.new(spending), status: :bad_request
  end
end
```